# JavaScript Regex: Get string between a match and another char

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

I have issues with the following text and Regex method. I retrieve the text from my server (from a Wordpress Database) and I want to extract the image `src` from it with Regex.

The string from the server looks like that:

```
...
[other_directives ...]
[et_pb_image admin_label="Bild" 
    src="http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/imageXYZ.jpg"
     show_in_lightbox="off" url_new_window="off" animation="left" sticky="off" align="left" 
    force_fullwidth="off" always_center_on_mobile="on" use_border_color="off" 
    border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid" alt="some text"]
[other_directives ...]
...
```

I want to search for the `et_pb_image` string and want to extract the text between the apostrophes of the `src` text in it.

Is this possible with pure Regex?

**EDIT**

What I tried till now (I'm a Regex beginner):

```
/(et_pb_image)?(src=").+[a-z]/
```

This returns the src but with the `src="..."` tag.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please post. Are you sure you need a solution in JS, and not PHP?

Comment: Can you share what did you try so far ?

Comment: @stribizhev I've updated my question with what I've tried before. Yes I need it in JS because I receive the string with AngularJS (Ionic App Development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be very careful with regex parsing such texts. Almost every time we have to assume something. So, in this case, let's assume you will not have `]` between the `et_pb_image` and the `src` attribute. Also, we assume that the src attribute value is enclosed with `"`.

Then, you can use

```js
var re = /et_pb_image[^\]]*?src="([^"]+)"/ig; 
var str = '...\n[other_directives ...]\n[et_pb_image admin_label="Bild" \n     show_in_lightbox="off" url_new_window="off" animation="left" sticky="off" align="left" \n    force_fullwidth="off" always_center_on_mobile="on" use_border_color="off" \n    src="http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/imageXYZ.jpg"\n[other_directives ...]\n...\n\n...\n[other_directives ...]\n[et_pb_image admin_label="Bild" \n    src="http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/imageXYZ.jpg" border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid" alt="some text"]\n     show_in_lightbox="off" url_new_window="off" animation="left" sticky="off" align="left" \n    force_fullwidth="off" always_center_on_mobile="on" use_border_color="off" \n    \n    border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid" alt="some text"]\n[other_directives ...]\n...\n...\n[other_directives ...]\n[et_pb_image admin_label="Bild" \n    src="http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/imageXYZ.jpg"\n     show_in_lightbox="off" url_new_window="off" animation="left" sticky="off" align="left" \n    force_fullwidth="off" always_center_on_mobile="on" use_border_color="off" \n    border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid" alt="some text"]\n[other_directives ...]';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.write(m[1] + "<br/>");
}
```

The regex is `/et_pb_image[^\]]*?src="([^"]+)"/ig` that matches

- `et_pb_image` - literal `et_pb_image`
- `[^\]]*?` - any characters other than `]`, as few as possible
- `src="` - literal `src="`
- `([^"]+)` - 1 or more characters other than `"` (assuming the src attribute value is enclosed in double quotation marks *always*)
- `"` - a literal `"`.

We need to get captured group 1 in all the matches, and it is impossible to achieve with `string.match`, we have to use `exec`.

Comment: Fab! Incidentally, I think it might work with just `/et_pb_image[^]*?src="(.+?)"/ig`. Finally it might be worth modifying your `str` to have different values for `src=...` to illustrate the code does actually extract the different instances of the match.

Comment: Yes, but `[^]` is not portable, and causes unnecessary questions :). Also, `.+?` is less effiecient than a negated character class.

Comment: @stribizhev thank you for your answer! works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript:

```
myLongString.match( /et_pb_image.+\s+src="(.+)"/g )
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Jvio3HCd5sfU4lZi)

Comment: @stribizhev - just curious, why do you think this won't work?

Comment: If `src` is not on the line below, it won't work. More, if another attribute is on the same line, it will overmatch. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX8jB9/1).